# Does there exist a proof of closure of regular languages under regular substitution by giving the corresponding DFA?

Tags: formal-languages, reference-request, finite-automata, closure-properties

Every proof I can find of this result is by way of regular expressions. Is there any "constructive" proof that defines the corresponding DFA (probably NFA)? For instance the proof of concatenation closure is most often presented by demonstrating the NFA. I'm just curious whether this is out there somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full specification of the construction of a finite automaton for regular substitution is given by Algorithm 4.2.7 of [1] (with a several-page proof of correctness). Tedious indeed!

[1] Meduna, Alexander. [Automata and languages: theory and applications](http://books.google.nl/books?hl=en&lr=&id=s7gEErax71cC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=automata+and+languages%3a+theory+and+applications&ots=__-q81OsQk&sig=62Bvl-EJ_PmExE5D_hgvFlyxpHo#v=onepage&q=automata%20and%20languages%3A%20theory%20and%20applications&f=false) Springer, 2000.

Answer (score 6):

There is a simple proof using automata. Suppose the original language is $L$, and we are substituting $R_a$ for $a$ (for each $a \in \Sigma$). Starting with an automaton for $L$, replace each edge $(x,y)$ annotated $a$ with a copy of an automaton $A_a$ for $R_a$, connecting $x$ to the starting state of $A_a$ with an $\epsilon$-edge, and connecting each accepting state of $A_a$ (which is not accepting any more in the new automaton) to $y$ with an $\epsilon$-edge.

Answer (score 4):

I would think that, given that there are contructive methods to pass
from one definition to another, about all methods used to prove these
things may be considered constructive.

Regarding NFA, if $R_a$ is the DFA for the regular set substituted to
$a$, then you remove any $a$-transition from state $p$ to state $q$ of
you original automaton, and replace it by an $\epsilon$-transition
from $p$ to the initial state of $R_a$ and $\epsilon$-transitions from
the final states of $R_a$ to $q$.  You must simply be careful to use a
different copy of $R_a$ for each $a$-transition, which entails
renaming all the states of $R_a$.

**Remarks** (following a comment by [sjmc](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/15486/sjmc))

Theorists need nearly none of these proofs specific to regular
sets. They use general proofs regarding full trios and full AFls
([abstract families of languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_family_of_languages)). Since the family of regular sets is
a full trio (which does have to be proved with some constructions), actually even a full AFL, it inherits a whole canned
collection of closure properties that have been
proved for all members of these families.

Explicit constructions are usually very simple for regular sets, so
that anyone with a tiny bit of experience in building automata can
imagine them. But they can also be tedious when you go into details.
Hence they are "left as an exercise" for whoever needs them.

The proof based on regular expressions is probably the most
interesting because of its architecture based on an [interpretation](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Interpretation_%28Formalized_Language%29) of
a formal [term algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_algebra), built on some operators corresponding to
closure properties of regular sets: union, concatenation, Kleene star,
and on a set of constants corresponding to the alphabet.  Regular set
are then a specific interpretation (morphism) of this
algebra,associating each term (i.e., regular expression) with a set of
strings on the alphabet, and each operator with the corresponding
operations on sets of strings. The interest of this approach is that
substitution of a variable by a term is a standard operation in term
algebras that stays within the algebra, and can thus be interpreted in the same domain. Hence the closure.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it's never explicitly given? Is it just much messier to formally describe than, for example, sequential automata for concatenation?

Comment: Also, yes I agree with your first statement, hence the "constructive". All I meant was a proof constructing automata from automata with no recourse to regular expressions

Comment: @sjmc Theorists need none of these proofs specific to regular sets. They use
general proofs regarding full trios and full AFls (abstract families
of languages). Since regular sets are full trios, even full AFls, they
inherit from a whole canned collection of closure properties. Explicit
constructions are very simple, so doable by anyone, but tedious. Hence
it is left as an exercise for whoever needs them. The proof based on
regular expressions is probably the most interesting because of its
architecture based on the interpretation of a formal algebra, in which
substitution is natural.